# How to catch/handle emitted errors within a series of pipes in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node-streams

I need to perform a series of transformations from a source of data. In the event that an error is emitted while data is being sent through the pipeline, I need to handle the error appropriately. Instead the response just hangs.

The only way I can close the hanging response is by calling `outStream.close(<string message here>)`, but that isn't much use because I would like to actually catch the error being emitted.

```
const seriesOfPipes = async () => {
  try {
      const streams = [transformStream1, transformStream2, transformStream3];
  
      const res = await fetch("foo");
      let outStream = res.body;
  
      for (const streamItem of streams) {
          outStream.on('error', streamItem.destroy.bind(streamItem));
          outStream = outStream.pipe(streamItem);
      }
      return outStream;
  } catch (e) {
      // the error doesn't appear
      console.log("you caught the error ", e.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My response was hanging because the response handler was not closing, I should've realized that from the start. Also, the `bind` was not necessary. So really what the error event handler should be doing is

```
outStream.on('error', (err) => {
  // sanitize error here
  const displayErr = sanitizeError(err);
  // pass displayErr to express response object
  resObj.writeHead(statusCode).end(JSON.stringify(displayErr);
}
```